Unable to use dual monitor after upgrade 22.4 to 24.4
I upgraded from 22.4 to 24.4 yesterday and now my dual monitor setup doesn't work anymore. They are two identical Dell's and are both detected.
My primary monitor works fine, my secondary monitor only shows the mouse cursor. No windows, no background, nothing else.
If I change from join to mirror in the display settings, they both work fine.
I have used RH/Fedora since the late 90's but am new to Ubuntu. Any ideas where I can start looking?

You don't mention what Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop? flavor?) but only releases; but I'll assume desktop.  If it was me, I'd likely boot a 24.04 system in live mode and see how it goes there? or if you have the same experience (further there are multiple 24.04 ISOs now that would allow testing of some upgrade changes)...   If you get the same experience on live and installed system, I'd likely assume its kernel related (or at least that's where I'd start exploring), where as if its different in live as against installed - look at config/changes you've made for differences...

FYI:  As you didn't mention product; 22.04 details I'd also consider; ie. if you were using the GA kernel stack on 22.04 then you're kernel change is to a far newer kernel (5.15 to 6.8), however if you used HWE at 22.04 then no change in kernel (unless you were behind on upgrades & still using 6.5).  If using OEM  .... etc    ie. I'd contrast changes in the software stack; kernel being one potentially significant change between releases - but clues as to what you were using would have been beneficial (ie. 22.04 using GA? HWE? OEM?.. or product so we have a default)

Apologies, it was the out of the box 22.04 desktop. Gnome through XOrg (Wayland was never working). Nothing non-standard. No gnome extensions.

Here’s the step-by-step process that fixed the issue for me:

Install the NVIDIA Driver open a terminal and run the following
command to sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-560

Select the NVIDIA Driver in Software & Updates Open Software &
Updates from the application menu. Go to the additional drivers tab and:
Select the option: "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-560
(proprietary)". Click apply changes and reboot your system.

Disable secure boot in BIOS:
During boot, enter your BIOS/UEFI settings locate the secure boot
option and disable it. Save the changes and exit the BIOS.



Got an N: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-560 in Ubuntu 24.04.

Check  ubuntu-drivers devices. This will list available drivers for your GPU, and it should suggest the correct driver version. Look for the recommended version and install it. And then use this sudo apt install nvidia-driver- suggested.Then reboot and do the steps above.
